# When does table id changes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

When does table id as recorded in system_schema.tables and data directory change and how does Cassandra read directories to get the latest schema

Looking at the data directory cd $CASSANDRA_DATA/keyspace/ I see two directories

drwxr-xr-x 4 cassandra users 4096 June 27 20:47 deviceData-c31406e0eda011e88cce75b7a7f02232

drwxr-xr-x 3 cassandra users 4096 June 30 15:22 deviceData-a0ba3490f28511e88cce75b7a7f02232

When querying the table schema I see

```
select keyspace_name, table_name, id from system_schema.tables where keyspace_name='devices' ;

keyspace_name | table_name | id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
devices | deviceData | a0ba3490f28511e88cce75b7a7f02232
```

So my question is: what causes id to change (is it alter statement ) as well as how does C* decide which structure to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table has a single UUID (and a single tablename-UUID directory) throughout its lifetime. The UUID is assigned on coordinator node when table creating statement is executed. The directories are created on replicas as they process schema change notifications.

You can get different tablename-UUID directories after you dropped a table and recreated with the same name. Only one table with a given name is active at a time.

You can also end up with two directories if you try to create a table with given name concurrently on two different nodes. You shouldn't try to do that though (https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/420)

[Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scylladb-users/mbb2iquAAEA)

Comment: Thank you! How does C* pick a table version to use on startup Is it by matching it to the id from system_schema.tables?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So in your case a0ba3490f28511e88cce75b7a7f02232 will be picked. I will suggest checking system_schema.tables in each node to make sure all of them have the same id in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one, but if you drop the table and recreate it there will be a 2nd table id.

There is also a race condition if you are calling `CREATE TABLE` concurrently on different nodes where they might create it with one table id, then converge with the rest of the clusters schema and switch to new table id. Bouncing cluster will resolve this if you see any cfid mismatch errors in logs. There are plans to fix this in future versions but 3.x still stuck like this.